# code to identify the number

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, tapi, netapi32

I got one problem while doing one TAPI application based project in C#. I'm using ITAPI3.dll

My problem is.. i'm not getting incoming call information. To get the incoming call information, i'm using the get_callinfo function, but it is showing empty message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a different modem?
TAPI is very hardware dependent

This might be a useful MSDN starting point:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726262%28VS.85%29.aspx

(if you didn't already have that url)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just experiencing the same problem. When i debug, a openfiledialog opens asking me to open a file. i'm no sure what it is right now, will get back when i find something. So i just skips the line of code, what causes it to be empty.

I found what was causing the problem for me :

get_callInfo has 3 constructors : one returning object, one returning int and one returning string. For some reason, the one returning object is failing. So i tried the string constructor. This gave me all the information i need. I'll give an overview of all attributes you can choose from :

e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLEDIDNUMBER);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLEDIDNAME);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLEDPARTYFRIENDLYNAME);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLERIDNAME);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLINGPARTYID);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_COMMENT);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CONNECTEDIDNAME);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CONNECTEDIDNUMBER);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_DISPLAYABLEADDRESS);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNAME);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_REDIRECTINGIDNUMBER);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNAME);
e.Call.get_CallInfo(CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_REDIRECTIONIDNUMBER);

hope this still helps